# Bug on login form while trying to close the app vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So currently I am using a code which provides me the possibility to manager whenever or not the application will logout or keep on track. Basically if the user is not using the program for quite some time it will move to the Login form and of course if the user wants to login back he had to type again.

I got a class where I am able to produce more or less that code:

```
Public Class TimerWatcher
    Private _timer As System.Threading.Timer
    Private _enabled As Boolean
    Private _lastEvent As DateTime

    Public Sub New()
        _timer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf watch)
        _enabled = False
        Timeout = 0
    End Sub

    Public Event Idle(sender As Form)
    Public Property Timeout As Long

    Public Property Enabled As Boolean
        Get
            Return _enabled
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If value Then
                _lastEvent = DateTime.Now
                _timer.Change(0, 1000)
            Else
                _timer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub watch()
        If DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastEvent).TotalMilliseconds > Timeout Then
            Enabled = False
            ' "End" is quite blunt. You may want to raise an event 
            ' so the form can terminate the application gracefully.
            RaiseEvent Idle(Login)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Refresh()
        _lastEvent = DateTime.Now
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then on my main form I got this:

```
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      watcher.Timeout = 5000
      watcher.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub PaginaInicial_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    watcher.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub watcher_idle(sender As Form) Handles watcher.Idle
    Dim logIN = New Login
    If MsgBox("The application will close, are you sure you want to do it?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        logIN.Show()
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

But, because some bug I am not able to return the Login form...And this is what happen to the form after I click yes on the MessageBox. The login form crash or something

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can solve this bug?

Comment: Don't display UI on a worker thread.  Use a regular System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead.

Comment: But use System.Windows.Forms.Timer on form on class?